# IntelliJ shows error using scalatags with boolean attributes

Tags: scala, dom, scala.js, scalatags

Does anyone now why IntelliJ is showing an error here even though sbt compiles and everything works correctly:

[image]

*Edit: "stopEnabled" is a Boolean.

As I understand, to not show an error here, I would have to write someting like this:

```
button(if(!stopEnabled) disabled else JsDom.Modifier.*nothing*)
```

Is there any way of solving this nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disabled` is a nuisance -- IMO, they spec'ed it wrong from the beginning, and have never made it better.

Offhand, I would guess that Scalatags' `frag()` constructor is probably the easiest solution: that takes its parameters and wraps them as a single frag. I believe that works even if there are no parameters.  So I think you could do:

```
div(
  if (stopEnabled)
    frag()
  else
    disabled := "disabled"
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've never seen this solution before even after a lot of googling. :)

Comment: It's a bit on the newer side, which may be why you didn't find it.  (I actually wrote my own version of `frag()`, years ago, because I found it desperately necessary for serious Scalatags work, but it seems to have shown up in the library itself a while back.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a sequence:

```
import scalatags.JsDom.all._

val stopEnabled = true

val modifiers = if(stopEnabled) Nil else Seq(disabled)

div(
  button(modifiers)
)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, that does not work because even if with `disabled="false"` the button is disabled! See: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html

(3.2.2 Boolean attributes
A number of attributes in HTML5 are boolean attributes. **The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.**
If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is a case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.)

Comment: I adjusted my answer

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. In the end I accepted @Justin 's answer because this way I dont have to introduce a seperate variable (here: 'modifiers'). When I tried to directly write your solution into the button()-body I got a "Expression of type Nil.type doesn't conform to expected type JsDom.Modifier"-Exception so the other solution seems 'better' to me in this regard. Thank you very much nevertheless. :)